# What is the largest possible size of a UIView in a Swift Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm trying to create a UIView in Swift Playground (in Xcode). My goal is to create the largest possible view. The current size is 1024 x 768. And if I try to increase the width or height, the view (when played in Live View) actually gets smaller which I think is happening so that it scales down to the window. 
But when I look at the Live View on 15-inch Macbook, there's a lot of space in the Live View -- the width can be increased, but I don't know how to increase it such that it actually takes up the entire screen.

Is there anyway to set the width to "full-screen"?

My code:

```
public class thisIsRandom: UIView {

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768))

        self.backgroundColor = .black
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

PlaygroundLiveViewRepresentation support size as per your screen display. I have MacBook Air 13 inch.

I have running live view in playground with 2048x1024 size, this show me large. This means it will show exactly on your screen size.

If same code will run in MacBook pro then it will smaller view, But, Also if your run this same code in iMac then it will display very small size of live view.

So, live view display on your MacBook, iMac screens size. I hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering!

So your point is that view sizing depends on the screen of the device? If my code has 1024 x 768 as the size of the view in Macbook pro 15 inch, it'll be scaled up to 2048 x 1024 on an iMac?

Comment: A question: 

What percent of the screen on your iMac does the 2048 x 1024 take when you toggle the live view screen all the way to the end such that the code is barely visible? 
On my Macbook pro 15 inch, with 1024 x 768 view size, there's almost 25% of the width left on the right. I don't understand why my view's width can't be bigger than 1024 points/pixels when the height is being fully occupied....any help?